# Getting screen width via javascript to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

for reasons that I won't get into here, I need to remove a plugin based on screenwidth.  I can use CSS to 'display: none' but that is not sufficient because the code is still there and it causes a conflict.  So I have been trying to get screen width via javascript and send that to the php file to keep the plugin from loading in this instance.  However, I'm unclear how to access that variable in php.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var sWidth = window.screen.width;
alert("sWidth is: " + sWidth);
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "wp-content/plugins/NKS-custom/main.php?width=" + sWidth;
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.onload = function() { 
    alert("Result: " + xhttp.responseText); 
};
xhttp.send(null);
```

I got this code from somewhere else and I am unclear if I should specify the index.php file for 'var url' or the actual plugin file.

I'd like to have an if/then statement in the php that executes the plugin code only if the screen width at certain size.  How do I grab the width from the javascript and how can I test to make sure the php is processing it? I saw something like this in the same forum answer but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$screen=$_GET["width"];
echo $screen;
```

Do I use "width" as in their example above or should I be grabbing the "sWidth" variable in the php (or something else completely)? And if so, what is the correct syntax? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: In Wordpress, you need to use [add_rewrite_tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) to let Wordpress know you're using a custom query variable.

Comment: No idea why you need the screen width in server-side but just so you know, customizing layout in server-side is usually a bad approach. If you can't fix your layout with CSS and HTML then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi cpilko, I'm looking at add_rewrite_tag on google but am not totally clear how that would work with above.

Comment: So didn't want to get into this but we have a custom plugin that they wanted which uses checkbox functionality for filtering (short story). They want a sliding panel for mobile to house this but I can't just 'hide' that sliding panel on mobile because the checkboxes are still there in the panel (i.e. they are in the sidebar on desktop and in the hidden panel) so the code only works on the first set of checkboxes (which is hidden). So somehow I have to have the sliding panel not even show up on desktop at all. Believe me, this has gotten way more complicated than I would have ever wanted too.

Comment: If you really want the mobile version to be more performant and have completely different controls use a sub-domain for the mobile version like m.example.com Then the server knows to server the mobile or desktop version.

Comment: Thanks, will try to do an alternate route.